# Browser addons in Windows 10 Kiosk mode

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, kiosk

Is there a way to install a browser addon (for example an adblocker) for the Microsoft Edge Browser thats running in a Windows 10 Kiosk? (Windows 10: Settings/Accounts/Family_and_other_users/Set_up_Kiosk)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft's
[Configure Microsoft Edge kiosk mode - Functional limitations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-configure-kiosk-mode#functional-limitations):

> We currently don't support the following features and recommend that
> you turn off:
>
> - InPrivateModeAvailability
> - IsolateOrigins
> - ManagedFavorites
> - EdgeShoppingAssistantEnabled
> - EdgeCollectionsEnabled
> - UserFeedbackAllowed
> - DefaultPopupsSetting
> - StartupBoostEnabled
> - InternetExplorerIntegrationLevel
> - **Extensions**
> - BackgroundModeEnabled
> - UserFeedbackAllowed

So at this time the answer is negative. This might change in the future.